# Git origin to bitbucket

Tags: git

I have a project I have cloned from a public repo to my PC which I have tweaked and pushed to Heroku.
I now wish to push my tweaked code to BitBucket as a backup.

```
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 13 commits.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)

nothing to commit, working directory clean

$ git remote
heroku
origin
```

When I try to add the BitBucket command it errors with:

```
fatal: remote origin already exists
```

That is, after:

```
$ git remote add origin git@bitbucket.org:me/myproject.git
$ git push -u origin --all # pushes up the repo and its refs for the first time
$ git push origin --tags # pushes up any tags
```

Would I correct in thinking I just have to update "`origin`" to point to BitBucket instead of the original repo?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Would I correct in thinking I just have to update "origin" to point to BitBucket instead of the original repo?

As a backup it is clearer to just add a new remote

```
git remote add bitbucket /url/to/your/bitbucket/repo
git push -u bitbucket --all
```

If you really wanted to change the remote '`origin`' (because '`heroku`' is enough), then it would have been:

```
git remote set-url origin /url/to/your/bitbucket/repo
```

No need for a git branch command, the push will create the bitbucket remote branch for you.

Answer (score 1):

So you don't want to add the remote again with the same name, that will always fail. There is nothing intrinsically special about the `origin` as a name except that it is the convention.

Your current branch is setup to track the remote `origin/master`. If you want to be able to push directly to your bitbucket as a new repo.

You can add a few remote named bitbucket pretty easy.

```
 git remote add bucket <repo-url>
```

And then you can update your current branch to be able to track the bucket master branch

```
git branch -u bucket/master
```

So when you run:

```
git push
```

it will push your changes directly to bitbucket.

Comment: I added my new remote and then tried git branch -u bucket/master however received the following error: "error: the requested upstream branch 'bucket/master' does not exist"

Comment: okay since the branch doesn't exist already, there is nothing to track before you first push it